Invalid parameter for estimator KerasClassifier _ GridSearchCV
I learn about hyperparameter Tuning on deep learning model, So I am trying to perform hyperparameter tuning using GridSearchCV with a Keras neural network classifier (KerasClassifier).
However, I am encountering an error related to the parameters that i try to tuning (activation,neurons,optimizer).
Here is my code (suppose X_train, y_train are provided):
def DL_Model(activation= 'relu', neurons= 5, optimizer='Adam'):

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(neurons, activation= activation))
model.add(Dense(neurons, activation= activation))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer= optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
return model

activation = ['softmax', 'relu']
neurons = [5, 10]
optimizer = ['Adam', 'Adamax']
param_grid = dict(activation = activation, neurons = neurons, optimizer = optimizer)

clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn= DL_Model, epochs= 5, batch_size=1024, verbose= 2)

model = GridSearchCV(estimator= clf, param_grid=param_grid)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

the parameters are being passed to KerasClassifier as part of the param_grid, but i don't know why KerasClassifier does not have the parameters.
I am getting the following error:
ValueError: Invalid parameter activation for estimator KerasClassifier.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!
